# Specifying the proper xticks label distance

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, plot

I have a Tikz plot which looks (roughly) as follows:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.13}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[
        title={My plot},
        xlabel=X label,
        ylabel=Y label,
        xtick=data,
        x=0.3cm,
        ticklabel style={font=\tiny},
        xticklabels={$x_1$ (test 1),$x_2$ (test 1),$x_3$ (test 1),$x_4$ (test 1)},
        xticklabel style={text width=0.9cm},
        ]
        \addplot coordinates {((1,1)(2,1)(3,3)(4,3)(5,3)(6,3)(7,3)(8,3)(9,3)(10,3)(11,5)(12,3)(13,3)(14,3)(15,3)(16,3)(17,3)(18,3)(19,3)(20,3)(21,3)(22,3)(23,3)(24,3)(25,3)(26,3)(27,3)(28,3)(29,3)(30,3)(31,3)(32,3)(33,2)(34,2)};
        \legend{$My legend$};
    \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

resulting in the following plot:
[image]

My question is now how I would go about creating a plot with proper xticks label spacing such that my xticks labels don't overlap.

Thank you very much for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

assuming that you do not want to change the x spacing, I would suggest using the *rotate* keyword to write the xlabels vertically:

`xticklabel style={rotate=70, anchor=east},`

which results in

[image]

Comment: Thank you. That does the trick. :-)